# How can I pass struct(not a pointer to struct) to Win32API call in ruby?

Tags: ruby, struct, ffi

I am trying to pass structure to Win32API call in ruby.

How can I do this?

A structure is not a pointer. So I can't code like following:

```
require 'win32api'
get_std_handle = Win32API.new('kernel32.dll',"GetStdHandle",['I'],'I')
h = get_std_handle.call(-11) # STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE

# ['I','P'] is wrong. COORD is not a pointer. it's a structure.
set_console_cursor_position = Win32API.new('kernel32.dll',"SetConsoleCursorPosition",['I','P'],'I') 
p = [10,10].pack('S*')
set_console_cursor_position.call(h,p)
puts "hello" # since above code is wrong, this will not printed at position 10,10
```

So the question is: How to pass structure (not a pointer) to Win32API call?

Comment: that's how these folks do it http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/win32console/1.3.2/Win32/Console/API.SetConsoleCursorPosition (click view source)

Comment: Also, reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/44270509/1292918 may help

Comment: @Toby, Thanks a lot! Will you post your comments as an answer? So that I can select your answer as a solution. Plus, will you let me know if the 'p' and shift trick also applicable to all sort of structure? (Or is it works only if structure size is 32bit? Like COORD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folks at [RubyDoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/win32console/1.3.2/Win32/Console/API.SetConsoleCursorPosition) have listed code for the source of their Win32Console gem, which uses this, as

```
def SetConsoleCursorPosition( hConsoleOutput, col, row )
  @SetConsoleCursorPosition ||= Win32API.new( "kernel32", "SetConsoleCursorPosition", ['l', 'p'], 'l' )
  dwCursorPosition = (row << 16) + col
  @SetConsoleCursorPosition.call( hConsoleOutput, dwCursorPosition )
end
```

Reading [How to pass structures as parameters to Win32API in Ruby (Array#pack and Array#unpack)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44270509/1292918) may also shed some light for you.

Unfortunately I'm not sure about the answer to your follow-up comment, maybe you could ask that as another question, or someone that knows could add another answer or comment here or indeed, feel free to edit this answer to add that information.

Comment: I copied and pasted above code and tried test. And ruby says it's unable to do method 'pack' because there is no implicit conversion of integer to into string.(at @SetConsoleCursorPosition.call) Can you give me some more hint?. (I learned that it is useful to check source code. Thanks anyway)

Comment: Have you tried passing in an actual number instead of `dwCursorPosition` to see check if it is a problem with your provision of the position? Other than that I guess you'd be better off asking a new question for that specifically

Comment: You need to change Win32API.new( "kernel32", "SetConsoleCursorPosition", ['l', '**p**'], 'l' ) for Win32API.new( "kernel32", "SetConsoleCursorPosition", ['l', '**L**'], 'l' ) how Toby said and it will work.